# Bootstrap Galaxy S6

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was developing a website for one of my clients and it is working pretty fine on most of mobile devices except few phone models like mentioned in topic Galaxy S6 (another models are probably iPhone 6 and HTC One). Those models has resolution as big as desktop's resolutions so the website is not displayed properly.

My question is:
-Do i have now to write proper media queries for all of this devices or there is some faster workaround (for example some simple "portrait" media query which will use Bootstrap's col-xs-* classes?
-Or i have to wait for Bootstrap 4 where it will be probably fixed?

P.S Sorry for my bad english tho.

Comment: I have the same Problem, but no you don't have to write different media queries. If you are correctly uing the viewport meta tag in your html, than the resolution being used for media queries is actually 360pxx640px. So it should use the col-xs classes. Unfortunately only the S6 seems to have a problem with that.

Comment: Thanks for response. Still fighting with it, damn stupid S6, hope Bootstrap 4 will have a fix for it (maybe recognizing some pixel ratio).